# Java: Warning: References to generic type should be parameterized

Tags: java, iterator

`currentProfile.getFriends()` method returns a Iterator over a ArrayList. It works as supposed but the compiler gives me a friendly warning when assigning it to another iterator: `iterator is a raw type. References to generic type Iterator <E> should be parameterized`

I have little or no idea what this means, care to enlighten me? if my description were not clear enough, this is what I am doing `Iterator friendList = currentProfile.getFriends();`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please look at the signature of the method getFriends() if you can. That should look like:

```
public Iterator<some type> getFriends()
```

the "some type" is the type you need to put in the Iterator reference.
For example if the method is:

```
public Iterator<Friend> getFriends()
```

use:

```
Iterator<Friend> friendList = currentProfile.getFriends();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
`Java: Warning: References to generic type should be parameterized`
```

what it means is you are assigning an object with the generic type set to a reference which has no generic type declared.

**Example:**

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Iterator itr=   list.iterator(); // you'd get that warning on this line, as you are not making iterator a generic type.

it'd disappear when you do this

 Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();
```

Comment: What happens if the code is compiled like that anyway? Is `Object` used as the type?

Comment: yup, that's the question to ask, Aaron

Comment: @Araon: If you don't give it, I don't see any problem in this case, but in few cases, the code might fail to cast at runtime. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790770/why-cant-i-assign-a-raw-type-to-a-parameterized-type-java?rq=1