# Why can't I assign a Raw Type to a Parameterized Type? (Java)

Tags: java, generics, types

If one assigns a Parameterized Type Object to a Raw Type Object, as I understand it the Raw Type Object assumed the Parameterized Type.  This makes sense to me.  But why can't it work the other way around?  I would think that after assigning a Raw Type to a Paramterized Type, the compiler would simply assume the Parameterized type.

Thanks for any help!

Alright, as I understand it, the following will work no problem, treating the Raw Type as if a String type were passed:

```
SomeClass<String> instance1 = new SomeClass<>();
SomeClass instance2 = instance1;
```

But the following will throw a warning and a type of String will not be implied in any of the class's methods:

```
SomeClass instance1 = new SomeClass();
SomeClass<String> instance2 = instance1;
```

I think I just figured it out, though, so if so I am sorry to waste everyone's time.  Does this work because instance2 is creating a pointer rather than a new object, and a pointer can't change the behavior of the object it is pointing to?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the raw type assumed the parameterized type"?

Comment: You will need to provide examples my man.

Comment: The compiler won't assume things unless it knows them to be true, for the same reason that you can't assign an `Object` to a `String`.

Comment: Alright, I just updated it.  I think I might have answered my own question though, so if someone could confirm that would be great.  Sorry for potentially wasting the board's time!

Comment: @JS: Your edited explanation is completely wrong; generics do not exist at runtime.  This is not allowed because purely it wouldn't be type-safe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generics are compile time only. Basically when the code gets compiled the parameterized types are erased and replaced with casts.

Consider something like the following:

```
class SomeClass<T> {
    T value;

    T get() {
        return value;
    }

    void set(T val) {
        value = val;
    }
}
```

When you declare a new `SomeClass<String>` it looks like what happens is like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    String value; // "value is now a String"

    String get() {
        return value;
    }

    void set(String val) {
        value = val;
    }
}
```

But that is not what actually happens. What actually happens is that SomeClass is always like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    Object value; // erasure of T is Object

    Object get() {
        return value;
    }

    void set(Object val) {
        value = val;
    }
}
```

And when you have a `SomeClass<String>`, whenever you say `String someString = someClass.get();`, the compiler inserts a cast from Object to String. There is no behavioral difference between a raw time and a parameterized type at run time, only whether there is a cast. That's why raw types are "bad", because there is basically no difference between a raw type and not using generics.

Try this:

```
SomeClass<String> pam = new SomeClass<String>();

((SomeClass)pam).set(new Integer(0));

System.out.println(((SomeClass)pam).get()); // prints 0
System.out.println(pam.get()); // ClassCastException
```

So to be clear, when you do this:

```
SomeClass<String> instance1 = new SomeClass<>();
SomeClass instance2 = instance1;
```

No types are "passed". `instance2` is not a `SomeClass<String>`.

When you do this:

```
SomeClass instance1 = new SomeClass();
SomeClass<String> instance2 = instance1;
```

You get a warning because it's *unsafe*. There's no guarantee that `instance1`'s value is a String but it will be casted to one if you call get on `instance2`.

Given the following snippet:

```
SomeClass<String> instance1 = new SomeClass<String>();
SomeClass instance2 = instance1;

System.out.println(instance1.get());
System.out.println(instance2.get());
```

The print statements compile to the following bytecode:

```
getstatic PrintStream System.out
aload_1 instance1
invokevirtual Object SomeClass.get()           // instance1.get() returns Object
checkcast String                               // which is casted to String
invokevirtual void PrintStream.println(String) // call println for String
getstatic PrintStream System.out
aload_2 instance2
invokevirtual Object SomeClass.get()           // instance2.get() returns Object
invokevirtual void PrintStream.println(Object) // call println for Object
```

As you can see, there's no difference except for the cast.

Comment: Thank you so much for the in-depth response.  I've really only got one question here, which is where you said that the raw "instance2" was not typecast as a String.  This might just point to a fundemental misunderstanding of the language on my part, but I thought that instance2 was a POINTER to instance1, meaning they would be identical.

Comment: They are the same object but the way generics are implemented, the type of the reference is what matters to the compiler. When you have a `SomeClass<String>` all the `<String>` effectively means is that T gets casted to String. The difference between that and not using generics is that with generics the compiler can provide checks for you. Honestly I think the bytecode is the best demonstration for how generics actually work. There's nothing "String" about `instance1` except for the cast during `get`.

Comment: Right, I did see that but just wanted to clarify to make sure I completely understood, which I do now.  Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, they seem a bit cumbersome and I'm not sure if I'll use them yet or not.  I'm basically completing Oracle's Java Trail in two sittings having no background in the language whatsoever, so only having experience in PHP/Javascript my head is spinning a bit and I'm not sure what I like and don't like quite yet.

Comment: The general opinion is that Java generics (erasure) leave some to be desired but they're still immensely useful. The upside to erasure is that reification is cumbersome to implement.

Comment: I'm not sure what reification is, but I imagine I'll find out when I need to.